# jQuery changes to cloned autocomplete widget, only change original

Tags: jquery, user-interface, autocomplete, clone

Sorry about the header, I really don't know how to simply put this question.  I have a function that clones a TR with all of it's child elements and renames them all (id and name), it adds the clone beneath the original.  One of the elements in the TR (currently only one, soon to be 4) is a jQuery UI autocomplete widget.

So my first problem is that when the new TR gets added, the decedent autocomplete widget is no longer a autocomplete widget - it's just a plain old text field.  This makes sense because I would have to apply a new $(foo).autocomplete(bar) to the newly created element.

So my next problem comes when I try to reapply the $(foo).autocomplete(bar) to the cloned element it seems to change the original element instead of the new clone!  I'm calling the $(foo).autocomplete(bar) at the same time that I'm making other changes to the same elements and those other changes work fine (ids and names).  After cloning the TR, the orginal behaves exactly how the clone should and the clone basically does nothing!

Sorry for the long explanation, here is the code:

```
    function cloneBelow(TR) {
        var newRow = $(TR).clone();
    var lastID = $(TR).attr('id');
    var currID = Number(lastID.substring(3));
    var newID = currID;
    var i = 0;
    while(i < 1){
    newID = newID + 1;

    if($(('#tr_' + newID).replace(/\./g, "\\.")).length < 1){
        i = 1;
    }
    }

    $(newRow).attr('id','tr_'+newID);
    $(TR).after(newRow);
    var i = 0;

    $('#tr_'+newID).find("[type=text],td,.cellContent").each(function(){
    var child = $(this);
    var newVal = child.attr("id");
    newVal = newVal.substring(0,newVal.indexOf("_")+1) +newID+newVal.substring(newVal.lastIndexOf("_"));
    child.attr("id", newVal);

    //apply changes to form autocomplete fields:
    if($(child).attr('name')){ //this will filter out any non-text fields
    child.attr("name", newVal);

    //Begin code to make element a autocomplete widget
    var tmpArray = ["test1","test2","test10"];
    $(child).autocomplete({
        source: tmpArray,
        select: function(event, ui) {
        var CTId = $(child).attr("id").substr(3);
        var selectedObj = ui.item;
        $('#CT_'+CTId).html(selectedObj.value);},
        minLength: 0
    }).addClass("ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-left");
    alert($(child).attr("id")+" - "+tmpArray);
    }
});

    $(".target").contextmenu(option);
    }
```

I'm not very experienced with jQuery (as you can probably tell), I've been working through countless issues with this project and I'm getting really close.

**EDIT:**
I tried using the .autocomplete( "destroy" ) method to revert the cloned element back to just a plain text field so I could then reapply the .autocomplete() and it actually removed it from both elements - not what I wanted.  However I learned that jQuery UI doesn't support cloning so apparently it's cloning the element but the clone and original are sharing the same widget or whatever.

I'm still looking for a recursive solution to this problem, as I have 4 similar functions and 7 different elements per row that need to be autocompletes - obviously I don't want to copy and paste the code 28 times and repeat every time I change something.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the jQuery [Live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) keyword with the autocomplete?

**edit**

I had a similar issue with an autocomplete plugin i was using.

I also, some time ago, simply did something like this;

```
$("#PositionsAvailableSkills").autoSuggest(...
```

after I had created the control and it worked fine.

Comment: So you did that instead of .autocomplete()?  Or after?  Are the parameters the same?

Comment: I don't know if the params are the same.  You're using a different control than I did so I suspect not.  The point I'm trying to make is that with the Live() keyword, when a control is created the events are attached.  Or, as i did later on, when I placed the new control on the page I then called the jQuery method to instantiate the plugin.